# Transfer a file from MacBook Pro to Amazon Fire TV stick

Tags: file-transfer

I have Amazon Fire TV stick.
I have to transfer 1 file abc.apk from MacBook to Amazon.
When I connect stick either using USB or using HDMI and USB it was not recognized by MacBook.
Then I tried to use FTP but I failed to connect from MacBook to stick FTP server.
I did similar thing on another stick but failed on this new one.
Something should be simple :) but I'm failing .
Could someone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks
I figured out myself by using Cloud solution. 
I copied file to OneDrive Cloud and then opened it on Fire TV stick. 
All set now.